# Text Compare result in c#

Tags: c#

I want to compare two text strings(nvarchar characters) & want to find their comparison result.
Example:

```
string 1: We loved our country.it is beautiful and amazing too.
string 2: We loved our nice country.it is beautifully  amazing too.
```

Expected result:

```
No. of change: 3 
they are: nice,beautifully,and.
```

i have tried:

```
private string TextComparison(string textFirst,string textSecond)
{
    Difference difference = new Difference();
    return result = difference.DifferenceMain(textFirst, textSecond);
}
```

I need a function `DifferenceMain()`.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: That sounds not a hard problem to face. Have you tried _anything_ to solve it?

Comment: yap.new word addition/delete is easy to count,but it is difficult to count when existing word modified.

Comment: `nvarchar` sounds as if it's actually in the database. Are you sure that this is a C# question?

Comment: please edit your question, giving us some examples of code you've tried. That way, we can help you more easily

Comment: Yap, the two strings  are  actually comes from database & i want to compare & find out the no of change in c#.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
        string st1 = "We loved our country.it is beautiful and amazing too";
        string st2 = "We loved our nice country.it is beautifully  amazing too";

        List<string> diff; 
        List<string> diff1;
        IEnumerable<string> str1 = st1.Split(' ').Distinct();
        IEnumerable<string> str2 = st2.Split(' ').Distinct();

        diff = str2.Except(str1).ToList();
        diff1 = str1.Except(str2).ToList();
```

**diff** will give you following result
nice
beautifully
_  (Space) - as your 2nd string contains extra space

**diff1** will give you following result
beautiful
and

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.

```
public string[] GetChanges(string one, string two)
{
    string[] wordsonone = one.Split(" ".ToCharArray());//Creates a string array by splitting the string into individual words.

    string[] wordsontwo = two.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
    List<string> changes = new List<string>();//Create a string list to contain all the changes.
    for(int i = 0; i < wordsonone.Length; i++)
    {
        if(!wordsontwo.Contains(wordsonone[i]))//If wordsontwo doesn't contain this word.
        {
            changes.Add(wordsonone[i]);//Add this word to changes
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordsontwo.Length; i++)
    {
        if(!wordsonone.Contains(wordsontwo[i]))
        {
            changes.Add(wordsontwo[i]);
        }
    }
    return changes.ToArray();
}
```

And in order to present it in your format, you would use the following.

```
string[] changes = GetChanges(string1,string2);
string text = "Numbers of Changes "+changes.Length+", these changes are ";
foreach(string change in changes)
{
    text += change+", ";
}
MessageBox.Show(text);
```